# Animation to push div's width smaller

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, animation

I would like to use a keyframe animation to make one `div` width expand, while making it push another `div`'s width smaller, but also pushing the content out of the shrinking container having it disappear.

This is where I have got to: https://codesandbox.io/embed/box-push-s6b6v

I have to `div`'s width changing, but the content inside them never disappears. I would like for the elements inside to be pushed off to the left rather than just being overlapped. Like they are being pushed of the screen, disappearing.

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  border-style: dotted;
  height: 100px;
  width: 318px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#one {
  border-style: dotted;
  border-color: red;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  min-width: 0px;
}

#columns {
  column-width: 50px;
  column-gap: 5px;
  column-count: 3;
  width: 200px;
}

#two {
  border-style: dotted;
  border-color: cadetblue;
  width: 0px;
  height: 100px;
  max-width: 200px;
  animation: enter-right 20s linear infinite;
}

#three {
  border-style: dotted;
  border-color: lightcoral;
  width: 100px;
  min-width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

@keyframes enter-right {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  10%,
  90% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  98%,
  100% {
    width: 100%;
    /* transform: translateX(100%); */
  }
}
```

```html
 <div id="container">
        <div id="one">
          <div id="columns">cat dog snake</div>
        </div>
        <div id="two">
          <div id="columns">cat dog snake</div>
        </div>
        <div id="three">three</div>
      </div>
```

I hope it made sense what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Have you tried `overflow: hidden` on the `#one` element?

Comment: @disinfor I tried adding `overflow: hidden` but I would like it to look like to contents gets push out of the div to the left, and `overflow: hidden` makes it become hidden from the right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because this first div with id `#columns` is set to `display: block;`. Add the following to fix this:

```
#one #columns{
   display: inline;
}
```

And add a background color to `#two`:

```
#two {
  background-color: white;
}
```

**extra:**
if you add

```
#three {
  background-color: white;
  z-index:20;
}
```

the text doesnt look like it randomly appears